# How to pass value from DB to Listview/Grid View via binding?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, binding, connection-string

I need to pass a value from a database to Listview via a binding. I managed to make static data by simply adding values to the List and linking them to the desired columns. But I don't understand how to make it so that I could display values from my database (I work through the connection string and MySQL).

What the markup looks like

```
  <ListView
                    Name="LVBuild">
                    <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding  ID}"
                            Header="ID" />
                        <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"
                            Header="Title" />
                        <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"
                            Header="Description" />
                        <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BuildData}"
                            Header="BuildDate">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

My model

```
 public class BuildModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string BuildData { get; set; }
        public int Architect { get; set; }
        public int Location { get; set; }
        public int Teg { get; set; }
    }

    public class BuildManager
    {
        public static List<BuildModel> GetBuilds()
        {
            List<BuildModel> items = new List<BuildModel>();
            items.Add(new BuildModel() {ID = 1, Title = "Test1", Description = "Desc1", BuildData = "12.12.2022", Architect = 1, Location = 1, Teg = 1});
            items.Add(new BuildModel() {ID = 2, Title = "Test2", Description = "Desc2"});
            items.Add(new BuildModel() {ID = 3, Title = "Test3"});
            items.Add(new BuildModel() {ID = 4, Title = "Test4"});
            return items;
        }
        
    }
```

How do I pass values from a model

```
public partial class BuildPageAdmin : Page
    {

        private List<BuildModel> Builds;
        public BuildPageAdmin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LVBuild.ItemsSource = BuildManager.GetBuilds();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use data binding: create a public property to hold the source collection and update it with data from your database. [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0)

If your collection is a `ObservableCollection` you can update it dynamically:

```xml
<Page>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}, Path=Builds}">

  </ListView>
</Page>
```

```cs
public partial class BuildPageAdmin : Page
{
  // Create a binding source for the ListView
  public ObservableCollection<BuildModel> Builds { get; }

  public BuildPageAdmin()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
 
    this.Builds = new ObservableCollection<BuildModel>();
    this.Loaded += OnPageLoaded;
  }

  private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    => UpdateBuildModels();

  // Dynamically update the source collection at any time
  private void UpdateBuildModels()
  {
    this.Builds.Clear();

    // Get data from database
    IEnumerable<BuldModel> newBuildModels = BuildManager.GetBuilds();

    // Update source collection with new data from the database
    foreach (BuildModel buildModel in newBuildModels)
    {
      this.Builds.Add(bulidModel);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass data to my model from the database? I tried to just send to the connection but it didn't work

Comment: I need to understand how to pass a value from the database in binding in a separate class. But thank you very much for the code that allows you to update the table

Comment: You originally asked *"I need to pass a value from a database to Listview via a binding"*. That's why my answer shows how to setup the binding. I think I have answered your question *"How to pass value from DB to Listview/Grid View via binding?"*.  Now you change your question to *"Can you tell me how to pass data to my model from the database?"*. This has nothing to do with your current question. You should open a new question to ask how to read data from your database.

Comment: Thenks BionicCode